# individual JS file XMLHttpRequest vs combined gzip download

Tags: html, performance, javascript

some stats before i can state the situation,

```
total JS code = 122 MB
minified = 36 MB
minified and gzip = 4 MB
```

I would like to get the entire 4 MB down in one shot (with a loading progress indicator on the page), uncompress them, but not parse them yet. We don't want the code expanding in browsers memory when a lot of it might not be required at this point. The parsing should happen when a script tag with the corresponding js file name is encountered.

Intention: faster one shot download of js files, but keeping the behaviour unchanged from the browser perspective.

Do any such solutions exist? Am I even thinking sane?
If yes, I know how to get the gzip, I would like to know how to keep them in the browser cache so that when a script tag is encountered the browser doesn't fire a XMLHttpRequest for it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to leverage HTTP caching directives. For a starter take a look at [this](http://www.httpwatch.com/httpgallery/caching/). You should only need to fetch your JS code once because you can safely set the cache directive to instruct the browser to hold on to the JS file indefinitely (subject to space). Indefinitely in this context typically means the year 2035.

When you're ready to update all your browser-side caches with a new version of the JS file simply use a cache busting Query String. Any serial number or time and date will do, or a simple version number eg;

```
<script src="/js/myfile.js?v2.1"></script>
```

Some minification frameworks handle the cache-busting for you. A good technique for example is those that MD5 the contents and use that as the cache buster query string. That way, whenever your source JS changes the browser will request the new version (because the QS is embedded in your HTML script tag) and then cache for as long as possible again.

XMLHttpRequest will honour the caching primities you set.

In the other part of your question, I believe what you're asking is whether you can download one combined script file and then only refer to parts of it with individual script tags on the page. No - I don't believe you can do that. If you want to refer to individual files you would need to have a HTTP URL and caching directives for each piece of GZIPped content you want to use separately. However, you might find this is as much or maybe even more performant than one big file at first depending on how much parallelisation you can achieve.

A neat trick here is to pre-load a lot of what you need. Google have been doing this on the home page for years. Basically, they pre-load stacks of resources (images certainly, but possibly also JS). So whilst you're thinking about what search query to enter, they are already loading the cache up with stuff you'll want on the subsequent page.

So you could use XMLHttpRequest to fetch your JS files (without parsing them) well before you need them. Then by the time your `<script/>` tag refers to them they'll already be downloaded and you just need to parse them.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Yes, the intention was to get all the files gzipped into one bit and uncompress them into various pieces locally again. But as you said, it would not work. Regarding fetching individual js files and not parsing them - are you referring to the defer flag behaviour? or is there some other way too? May be just making the XMLHttpRequest and getting the file - not populating it in the script tag on the page. But in that case, can i hold on to the contents as strings and populate them as and when required later? Is there any library which does this?

Comment: Yep. Just fetching the JS files iwth XMLHttpRequest will populate the cache. When you then refer to the URLs in your Script tags they'll be loaded (parsed) from the cache. You don't need to hold onto the strings. Having said that, you should take a look at RequireJS, it might be just what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to cirrus's point about using HTTP caching, you could break that still-pretty-large 4mb file down and only load them when that functionality is required.

It's more HTTP requests, but 4MB is a big hit in one go.

Suggest something like require.js to load in the appropriate files when they are needed:
http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html

Comment: the present model works exactly the way you said it should be. hundreds of smaller individual chunks, which are fetched as and when required. Was trying to evaluate all the different possibilities